# Trying to run a PowerShell script on version 2.0

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to run the statment on PowerShell 2.0:

```
$fixDepositsDataFile = Import-Csv F:\Balink\PowershellScripts\Wbalqry0.CSV -Header "1"
$fixDepositsDataFile | %{
    if ($_.1 -eq " ") {$_.1 = " "}
}
```

And I'm getting this exception:

[image]

I worked perfectly on 5.0, but the server that will run the script is 2.0.

Any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: `.1` --> `.(1)`

Comment: Without the underscore? Like this: if($(.1) -eq " ") {$(.1)=" "}? because it doesn't work =\

Comment: Like this: `$_.(1)`.

Comment: Thanks PetSerAI, It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you cannot use integers as property names in PowerShell v2. There are a number of ways to work around this issue. For instance you could put the property in an expression as [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455478/trying-to-run-a-powershell-script-on-version-2-0#comment72053670_42455478) suggested (`$_.(1)`) or use a variable (`$p = 1; ... $_.$p ...`).

Personally I prefer putting the property name in quotes:

```
$fixDepositsDataFile | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.'1' -eq " ") {$_.'1' = ""}
}
```

Quotes around property names also help mitigating other problematic scenarios, e.g. when a property name contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: Why won't they? I don't have a real PS2 but quotes help in PS5 launched as v2: `powershell -version 2 -c "$s=[pscustomobject]@{'1'='a'}; $s.'1'"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tested the code with PowerShell v2 on an XP test box, and it worked just fine. Please elaborate.